# Xcode user defined runtime attributes not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

From the posts I've found, it seems like this should work, but I can't get my runtime attribute to take.  I'm developing for OSX 10.7 using Xcode 4.2.1.  Here is the setting in IB:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
#import "BILAugmentedScrollView.h"

@implementation BILAugmentedScrollView {

    BOOL _ignoreScrollWheel;
}

@synthesize ignoreScrollWheel = _ignoreScrollWheel;


- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    NSLog(@"scroll ignore = %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.ignoreScrollWheel]);

    if (self.ignoreScrollWheel)
        [self.nextResponder scrollWheel:theEvent];
    else
        [super scrollWheel:theEvent];
}
```

My output, however, is this:  [7411:707] scroll ignore = 0

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've read somewhere else that the attributes don't work when using a custom initWithCoder implementation.

*(Also, kudos for using 3-letter "namespace" prefixes, as Apple (rather silently) suggested to do. I'm a bit worried that especially the Cocoa old timers keep ignoring this rule and keep using 2 letters only.)*

Comment: There didn't used to be enough developer companies to have to worry about name collisions, so old devs just used two-letter prefixes/suffixes. Now we have thousands of individual devs and massively expanded Apple API and people forget we need three. That's especially true with all the code swapping and borrowing we do now.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, the problem seems to relate to the fact that this object ("BILAugmentedScrollView") is used in an NSCollectionView:  when it stands alone, changing the attribute in IB works just fine.  I don't know why the problem occurs, since each instance of the object is loaded from the nib by the collection view, but it does.